# How to make a callback URL in PHP?

Tags: php, api, callback

So I've been searching the net diligently and I can't seem to find a good(and basic) example of a callback. I get the idea of a callback but I can't make it work. Here's my sample code:

```
$fp = fopen("file.txt","wb"); 
fwrite($fp,"sample content");
fclose($fp);
```

Basically what it does is create a new txt file once it is triggered. This is just an example. Once I can get this functional, I can proceed to a more complicated one. But this doesn't work at all.

This is how I call the callback:

http://api.sample.com/post/12123232?callback=http://myurl.com/post/save

Is there anything that I missed here? It's also worth noting that the link above is submitted thru curl.

Comment: This is supposed to read an HTTP(S) POST?  You're reading from stdin ....

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey ideally yes. but that's really not the problem here. I just want to make sure that my callback is being triggered. :)

Comment: The code you provided is correct. Check your PHP/webserver logs and the output when you fetch the callback URL.

Comment: I suppose we should also mention you're not checking the return value of fwrite().

Comment: What is the callback URL supposed to do?

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey as i've said, this is just a sample script to check if my callback is getting called. I dont need to put a checker of the returns. I think I also should mention that if I access my callback url in a browser ,it successfully creates the txt file, but if I run it thru the api, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ceejayoz it should get the POST responses then save it to the database. but right now, my only concern is to know why my callback URL is not getting called. Based on the sample script above, it should create a file once triggered.

Comment: @user3437905 So `api.sample.com` is something out of your control, and it has a feature where passing a `callback` parameter to it will cause your URL to be hit when the API task/call is complete? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @ceejayoz correct. api.sample.com is a third party url wherein they generate a json type response when you access it. according to their documentation, if you want to get those responses, you will have to add a callback url. that's what I did but it's not working.

Comment: Was `myurl.com`'s DNS changed recently? Do your webserver's access logs show requests to that URL? Have you checked with the `api.sample.com` vendor?

Comment: @ceejayoz I know this is stupid but how do you check the logs? and is that significant here? :)

Comment: @user3437905 Yes, it's potentially very significant. Log location can vary, but knowing where they are is critical for general PHP dev. Take a look in `/var/log` on a Linux box. Looking at the access logs will tell you if the requests are hitting your server at all.

Comment: @ceejayoz but I don't have access to api.sample.com so I couldn't check.

Comment: You need to look at **your** logs. You want to see if `post/save` is showing up anywhere in them. If there are requests and there's a `404` status code, you've got the wrong URL. If there are requests and they're `500`ing, there's some sort of PHP error. My bet would be permissions issues with `fwrite`.

Comment: @ceejayoz the callback url successfully creates the txt file when you access it deliberately on a browser. I don't think there's a permission issues. Just my thought.

Comment: Then you're back to a) checking the logs and b) if nothing there, contacting the API vendor.